# How to specify my databases name into JDBC -> MySQL connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

What is the way to connect with JDBC to a mySql database that is online?

**mysql.info.mi.us:3006** = *corresponds to the server of the database*

**mydatabases_2** = *my databases*

*my try returning this error:*

> java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
connexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.info.mi.us:3306", "user", "password");
```

Comment: `Class.forName` no longer is needed.

Comment: Show your `StackTrace` and more code.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your JDBC connection.  You have a NullPointerException because something is not initialized.  We are able to hack into your computer to solve the problem, but choose not to do so.  Instead, consider posting the exception output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append it:

```
connexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.info.mi.us:3006/mydatabases_2", "user", "password");
```

Comment: always the same error "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: U sure you are using the right port? sql db's tend to be on 3306 instead of 3006

Answer (score 0):

Just a question: are you sure about the port?
The default port of mysql is 3306, while you're using 3006. Are you sure the port is right?